# Как не терять фокус?

Tags: java, android

Дело в том что у меня есть Видео Плеер использую [библиотеку](https://github.com/lipangit/JieCaoVideoPlayer) и перед ним `ImageView`, то есть типа баннера, которая закрывает 30% видеоплеера. Каждые 15 секунд картинка должна меняться.

```
mBannerView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
Thread.sleep(1000 * 15);
```

Но у меня крешится при изменении картинки с сообщением:

> Android “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can
>   touch its views.”

Попробовал вписать эти строки в `UI` потоке:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ............
    }
});
```

но тогда `ImageView` никак не реагирует ни на таймер, ни на изменение.

Я щас думаю (может и не прав, в таком случае поправьте пожалуйста) что фокус лежит на плеере так как видео играет и поэтому картинка находящаяся над ним когда меняется, грохается.

Если так то как быть в таком случае, как не терять фокус с `ImageView` при этом и видео продолжало играть?
А если нет, то в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем уверен, что именно такой вариант правильный, но, если Ваш плеер — это одна из реализаций `Android`'ского `View`, попробуйте вызвать на нем метод `.requestFocus()`, он сфокусирует экран на Вашем плеере.